# Android localized app

Tags: android, localization

Am developing an Android application; It has Arabic/English localization setup.. I followed the documentation and created different folder for each language under

- res

  - layout
  - layout-ar
  - values
  - values-ar

as far as I know that the device/emulator should pickup the resources depending on the user/device settings.. but I found that whatever the locale settings on the device/emulator. the app will load resources fro *-ar folders..

In code I never set or change the locale.. anybody knows why? It is really driving me crazy.

Comment: Check this http://www.kobu.com/i18n/android/index-en.htm

Comment: than you Virag; I followed a similar approach to that mentioned in the link; but still switching language does not change loaded resources; getResource().getStringArray(R.array.pages) will still return Arabic strings while the device Locale is English

Comment: Can you post sample code to reproduce this problem?

Comment: My code is straight forward; String[] pages = getResource().getStringArray(R.id.pages) this piece of code should return the string array based on the device locale but it doesn't it always returns the Arabic version no chnages to locale settings from within code whatsoever.